# Error Adding Columns in Powershell: 'You Cannot Call a Method on a Null-Valued Expression"

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to append a couple of columns onto a CSV file in Powershell, but for some reason the variables seem to have Null values even though I am trying to populate them. Specifically, I'm having trouble with the line

```
$Stats2.Columns.Add($colVZA)
```

which is apparently passed a null value by

```
$colVZA = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn VZA,([double])
$colVZA = $filename[0].VZA
```

I thought trying to populate it with data from the first cell in the VZA column in $filename would 'un-null' it, but apparently that's not how it works. Any ideas on how to get these columns populated and appended to the table? Here is my full code:

```
$i = 1


While ($i -le 211) {

#Set the variable to the filename with the iteration number
$filename = "c:\zMFM\z550Output\20dSummer\fixed20dSum550Output$i.csv"


#Check to see if that a file with $filename exists. If not, skip to the next iteration of $i. If so, run the code to collect the 

statistics for each variable and output them each to a different file
If (Test-Path $filename) {


#Calculate the Standard Deviation
#First get the average of the values in the column
$STDEVInputFile = Import-CSV $filename

#Find the average and count for column 'td'
$STDEVAVG = $STDEVInputFile | Measure-Object td -Average | Select Count, Average
$DevMath = 0

# Sum the squares of the differences between the mean and each value in the array
Foreach ($Y in $STDEVInputFile) {
$DevMath += [math]::pow(($Y.Average - $STDEVAVG.Average), 2)

#Divide by the number of samples minus one
$STDEV = [Math]::sqrt($DevMath / ($STDEVAVG.Count-1))

}

#Calculate the basic statistics for column 'td' with the MEASURE-OBJECT cmdlet
$STATS = Import-CSV $Filename |
Measure-Object td -ave -max -min |

#Export the statistics as a CSV and import it back in so you can add columns
Export-CSV -notype "c:\zMFM\z550Output\20dSummer\tempstats$i.csv"

$STATS2 = Import-CSV "c:\zMFM\z550Output\20dSummer\tempstats$i.csv"

#$colSTDDEV = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn StdDev,([double])
$colVZA = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn VZA,([double])
#$colVAZ = New-Object System.Data.DataColumn VAZ,([double])

#Append the standard deviation variable to the statistics table and add the value

$colVZA = $filename[0].VZA 
#$colVAZ = $filename[0].VAZ #COMMENTED FOR DEBUGGING
#$colSTDDEV = $STDEV

#$STATS2.Columns.Add($colSTDDEV) #COMMENTED FOR DEBUGGING
#$STATS2[0].StdDev = $STDEV #COMMENTED FOR DEBUGGING


$STATS2.Columns.Add($colVZA) |
#$STATS2[0].VZA = $VZA *****This line may be unnecessary now

#$STATS2.Columns.Add($colVAZ) #COMMENTED FOR DEBUGGING
#$STATS2[0].VZA = $VAZ #COMMENTED FOR DEBUGGING 

#Export the $STATS file containing everything you need in the correct folder



Export-CSV -notype "c:\zMFM\z550Output\20dSummer\20dSum550Statistics.csv"

}
$i++
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throughout your script, the value of `$filename` is a string. When you index into a string, like this:

```
$filename[0]
```

you get an object of type `[char]` (a character) returned:

```
PS C:\> "string"[0]
s
```

A `[char]` doesn't have a property called `VZA`, so this:

```
$colVZA = $filename[0].VZA
```

is essentially the same as this:

```
$colVZA = "C".VZA
```

which (since `VZA` doesn't exist) ends up like:

```
$colVZA = $null
```

even though `$filename` is non-null